# Evaluate the triple integral of $x^2+y^2$ where D is a pyramid

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate the triple integral of $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ where the region of integration is the pyramid with top vertex at $(0,0,1)$ and base vertices at $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(1,1,0)$.

I know how to evaluate triple integrals, but I always have trouble finding the bounds of integration.
If someone could please explain how to figure out what the bounds are, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: First thing to do is draw a picture.  Then I try to bound it between two (or sometimes more) planes in one of the directions (assuming we're working in Cartesian or cylindrical coordinates, though there is an analogous method that work in spherical).  Then I just need to look at cross sections which I can evaluate with Fubini's theorem.  [Here is a pretty good explanation](http://mathinsight.org/triple_integral_cross_section_method).

Answer (score 0):

Since the integral of $x^2+y^2$ over the set $E_t=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:0\leq x,y\leq t\}$ is given by:
$$ I_t = \int_{E_t}(x^2+y^2)\,d\mu = 2\int_{E_t}x^2\,d\mu = 2t\int_{0}^{t}x^2\,dx = \frac{2}{3}t^3 $$
the wanted integral equals:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}I_{1-t}\,dt = \frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{1}t^3\,dt = \frac{1}{6}.$$